# Rendered div height different when margin and height value different

Tags: html, css, height, margin

I am trying to create a stack of lines using divs. What seems to be a relatively simple task has left me boggled because the rendered height of the divs are not the same while they are given the same height in css. Funny thing is, if the margin-bottom value is the same as the div height, div heights renders correctly. But, I want the margin to be twice that of the div height. Here is my code.

```css
.line-wrap{
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   transform: translateY(-50%);
   width: 400px;
  }

  .line{
   background: rgb(0,0,0);
   /* display: inline-block; */
      /* display: flex; */
   height: 2px;
   width: 100%;
      /* box-sizing: border-box; */
      /*margin-bottom: 2px;*/
   margin-bottom: 4px;
   
  }
```

```html
<div class="line-wrap">
   <div class="line"></div>
   <div class="line"></div>
   <div class="line"></div>
   <div class="line"></div>
   <div class="line"></div>
   <div class="line"></div>
  </div>
```

I've tried different suggestions from different SO posts but nothing seems to work. What's happening here? What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. I see six parallel lines of equal height, in Firefox and Chrome. What browser are you using? Can you include a screenshot? Here is mine: http://tarm.wdfiles.com/local--files/stack-overflow-files/lines.png

Comment: funny stuff. I'm using chrome 70.0.3 & firefox 63.0.1 Tested with edge as well. Here is my screenshot. [https://ibb.co/n5TCYV]

Comment: New link https://pasteboard.co/HMGvxz8.png

Comment: @Antonio in this case, check if there is any zoom active

Comment: Nah, everything is normal.